# Simple array not working right

Tags: c++, arrays, random

This is supposed to simulate 2 6-sided dice being thrown, adding +1 to an element of an array acquainted with the result. E.g: a[4] holds how many 4's are rolled. For some reason, no matter how many times it rolls, it gives me 1 for every element in the array. I.e: (a[2] = 1, a[3] = 1, a[4] = 1, etc.)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;

int throwDice()         // generates random number ranging 2-12
{
    int x = (rand() % 6) + 1;
    int p = (rand() % 6) + 1;
    return x + p;
}


int main()
{
    srand (time(NULL));
    int y;
    cout << "Roll dice how many times?" << endl;
    cin >> y;

    int a2[12];                   // initializes and declares elements a[2] - a[12] with value 0
    for (int i = 2; i <= 12; i++)
        a2[i] = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i <= y; i++)   // runs random number generator, adds +1 to that element
        {
        a2[throwDice()]++;
        }

    for (int i = 2; i <= 12; i++)   // prints how many results per element
    cout << i << " = " << throwDice[i] << endl;
    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: You're screwing up your indices. There is no `a2[12]` - the last object in `a2` is `a2[11]`.

Comment: Instead of using an array, I suggest you look e.g. [`std::unordered_map`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map).

Comment: @JoachimPileborg - this seems like a perfect case for an array (once the indexing gets sorted out). Why add the overhead of an unordered map?

Comment: @PeteBecker It might be okay in this situation, I just want to point out there are other containers available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
cout << i << " = " << throwDice[i] << endl;
```

should be

```
cout << i << " = " << a2[i] << endl;
```

You should always use `-Wall` when compiling your code, that would have shown you immediately that something is wrong:

```
Compilation finished with warnings:
source.cpp: In function 'int main()':
source.cpp:33:38: warning: pointer to a function used in arithmetic 
                           [-Wpointer-arith]
```

---

Also, array indices start at 0, so to be able to access `a2[12]`, it has to have size 13 at least.

---

Finally, `system("pause");` is a questionable idea. I'd prefer `cin.get();` to wait for the user to press any key.

Comment: New problem, now it only runs once. So if I roll 2321 times, everything = 0, except for 1 number which = 1.

Comment: `int a2[12]; for (int i = 2; i <= 12; i++) a2[i] = 0;` looks nasty as well. Arrays are zero-indexed.